# wordpress multisite network custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I'm looking for an option to make custom post type that will be availble to the super admin only (wordpress multisite) and I'll have the option to add new posts to this custom post type from each of the network websites (via frontend insert post).

Comment: This is pretty hard to do, I suggest you start using the Wordpress codex on custom post types.